# Can one ElasticBeanstalk environment ever have multiple AutoScaling groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, autoscaling

I was looking at the AWS SDK to get information about my EB environment when I found that it appears that the SDK is returning AutoScaling groups as an array.

Can an EB environment even have multiple autoscaling groups?

And why might multiple autoscaling groups be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Elastic Beanstalk environment would have an Elastic load balancer on it and that allows for multiple auto scaling groups. One use of multiple Auto Scaling groups is blue/green deployments. You can spin new version of an application, test it, attach it to the load balancer to receive production traffic and slowly terminate old instances. You can read more about blue/green deployments [here](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments.pdf)

Comment: I would like one ASG to not be behind the LB, but to run Sidekiq or other non-web process. so I can have 4 ec2 instance on that ASG and 4 on my web ASG and defined the nodes independently. Should I post this as a separate question ?